# How can I make a .bat file change all files name the way i need it too

Tags: batch-file, rename

First sorry, I know this has been answered 100 times but I don't understand how to make the scripts I find do what I need.

Second sorry, I asked this a few days ago but was not thinking right at the time and my post was put on hold or something..

Okay, I need to edit multiple file names at once.

The files will always start and end with the same things example: "MOVIES Iron Man 3 watch now.flv"

I need to remove the "MOVIES " and " watch now" from the file titles. I have no clue how to do this nor where to start. If someone can show me a working example or write me a simple script that someone with no understanding of .bat file scripts can use it would be awesome!

Please and thank you!

If it helps I run windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a non-destructive solution that will merely write a file called `renfiles.bat.txt` and you can examine it in Notepad to see if it is doing what you want, before renaming it to a batch file and launching it to do the renaming.

It depends on the exact text being typed where you see it in the batch file, and the space after `Movies` as well as the space before `watch` is included in the change.

Change the `c:\base\folder` to the path where all your folders and file are.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\base\folder"
dir /b /s /a-d |repl ".*\\MOVIES (.*) watch now(.*)" "ren \q$&\q \q$1$2\q" ai >renfiles.bat.txt
```